# Virtually sequentially concatenate two C++ std::vectors

Tags: c++, oop, templates, std

The goal is to *virtually* (which means no real concatenation should occur) sequentially concatenate two C++ std::vectors of objects of different types for the time of function call.

I have objects of some classes in different vectors and want some functions to process them as whole. I don’t want to use virtual functions, dynamic memory allocation neither put all objects of different types (pointers to them) in the same container, since in most of code they treated differently and I don’t won’t to pay extra price neither to make complicated interfaces for my classes.

Here is the draft:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  void foo() { std::cout << "Hey, I'm A!\n"; }
};

struct B {
  void foo() { std::cout << "Hey, I'm B!\n"; }
};

void bar(???) {
   ???.foo();
}

int main()  {
    std::vector<A> va(2);
    std::vector<B> vb(3);

    bar(???);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, I can process all these vectors one by one, but I have many of them and this would lead to code duplication and risks of forgetting to update such code when a new type is added.

**Update**
Later I discovered that I really need not the concatenation at the function call moment, but an alias for dynamically concatenated vectors and the accepted answer below covers both.

Comment: You'll need to give a lot more detail of exactly what you're trying to do before anyone will be able to give you an answer. A [mre] is what you've tried and what problems you're having with it might help

Comment: *"sequentially concatenate"* -- Is there another way to concatenate?

Comment: @JaMiT, well this is a question of wording, but my intention is to stress that I don't want to have a kind of SoA (structure of arrays) to AoS (array of structures) transformations like zip functions in some libraries (thrust, std::ranges::views::zip, etc.) do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do some metaprogramming using [variadic parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) and [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). For example:

```
template<class... Ts>
void bar(Ts&... vecs) {
    const auto call_foo_for_each = [](auto& vec) {
        for (auto& v : vec)
            v.foo();
    };
    (call_foo_for_each(vecs), ...);
}

void caller()  {
    bar(va, vb /*, ... */);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8TejPEWM8)

If you want to pass them as a single argument, you could pack them into a [tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) (of references):

```
template<class... Ts>
void bar(std::tuple<Ts...> tuple) {
    const auto call_foo_for_each = [](auto& vec ) {
        for (auto& v : vec)
            v.foo();
    };
    std::apply([&](auto&... vecs) {
        (call_foo_for_each(vecs), ...);
    }, tuple);
}

void caller()  {
    bar(std::tie(va, vb /*, ... */));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is almost exactly the solution I am looking for! Just one extra question, is there is something in standard library (like accumulate/transform/etc.) which could be used to avoid writing this code for bar? I love the solution, but in case we have something to make it shorter, it would be excellent. I truly believe that this task of enumeration is a kind of a pattern for standard library and should already be implemented somewhere. (I will use your code as a minimal reproducible example in my question if you don't mind, as AlanBirtles asked.)

Comment: @DamirTenishev I don't think you could shorten this code using the standard library. Unfortunately, the standard library is not that rich when it comes to metaprogramming.

Comment: @DamirTenishev And even with Boost I can't think of a shorter solution.

Comment: Thank you again. Reading the answer from @SRNissen (as well as this could be seen from your answer) I realized that I asked a wrong question. Calling with list of functions won't help me since I will have to update all these lists of va,vb,etc. in every caller function. What I really needed is to have an alias for virtual concatenation of such vectors. It seems that your answer covers this perfectly; I just need to store the tuple, update it as a list of all my vectors when needed and use in any caller I need. Is this correct, would it work or it is another question (to open)?

Comment: @DamirTenishev From a text description it's hard to say. Try to implements and see if it works or not. The main limitation you have with this approach is that vectors you're putting into a tuple should be known at compile time. That is, you can't do something like "push_back" on a tuple in runtime, because that operation would change the tuple type, which C++ doesn't allow.

Comment: So, my idea is https://godbolt.org/z/W4a839x6v and it seems to be working. The only significant difference is in line 15. Just asked to make sure that it is valid to store the tuple in this particular situation. Thank you again!

Comment: @DamirTenishev Your code is correct. In general, make sure that references a tuple holds are not invalidated before that tuple is used.

Comment: @DamirTenishev Simplified using suggestion by Artyer.

Comment: I tried to wrap up my code from https://godbolt.org/z/W4a839x6v to a struct and meet an issue: https://godbolt.org/z/KbqnWenY9 . Could you please help me realize how to make this compile? Is it possible without listing all the types in make_tuple? I just want to have the all_objects in my class.

Comment: @DamirTenishev Unfortunately, you can't use deduction for `std::tuple` if it is a data member. `std::tuple<std::vector<A>&, std::vector<B>&> all_objects = std::tie(va, vb);`.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. Unfortunately, even this version didn't work (https://godbolt.org/z/vGzo7Pvnz); only with types specification on both sides do: std::tuple<std::vector<A>&, std::vector<B>&> all_objects = std::tie<std::vector<A>&, std::vector<B>&>(std::ref(va), std::ref(vb));   Thank you again, this helped a lot!

Comment: @DamirTenishev With `std::tie()` you don't need `std::ref()`. It should be `std::tie(va, vb);`.

Comment: Ops, thank you for catching this. They are leftovers from tries. Now meet another issue, when this is put in the class, the default assignment doesn't work since, of course, the references in the copy will we wrong and I don't want to implement my own copy, since the class is complex enough. Anyway, this is already another story for another question. Thank you for helping with this!

Answer (score 3):

> The goal is to virtually (which means no real concatenation should occur) sequentially concatenate two C++ `std::vector`s of objects of different types for the time of function call.
>
> My understanding that this is not doable since it is impossible at compile time to generate the code that will handle objects of different types (in the function) without usage of dynamic polymorphism.

If all the types are known at compile time, you can do it with static polymorphism - your concatenating view would, when dereferenced, return not the underlying elements but an object that contains a `std::variant` with a pointer to the underlying type.

It wouldn't be very elegant though.

However - seeing your example - have you considered a template function approach? If `A` and `B` both have a method `foo` you could

```
template<typename Vec>
void do_foo(Vec const & vec)
{
    for(auto & element : vec)
        element.foo()
}

do_foo(va);
do_foo(vb);
```

and now you don't need to worry about forgetting to update a function for one of the vectors if new requirements show up as they're all stamped from the same template.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Despite the fact that the answer from Evg is more comprehensive, your answer helped me understand that I made wrong question. I can't "not worry now about forgetting to update a function" since I have this list of do_foo(va), etc. and in my case I will have many arrays and many places where I will have to fix this. Now I see from the answer from Evg how to resolve this, I will store the tuple as an alias.