# Handling different objects similarly in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I have to store huge arrays of different types of objects which are not related to each other but share some common parts of interface (have similar methods for initialization, setup, render, etc.). What would be the best way to store them so that I could write client code once, not repeating it for each container?

Now I have (class names and signatures of the methods just for demo purposes):

```
struct Device {
   virtual void render();
};

struct Sensor : Device {
   virtual void render();
   void connect();
};

struct Regulator : Device {
   virtual void render();
};

class Scheme {
   std::vector<Device*> devices;
   std::vector<Sensor> sensors;
   std::vector<Regulator> regulators;
   // many containers
};
```

and so on (many classes). I use *sensors*, *regulators* to pack the objects so that I could process only small amount of objects of the necessary type; to avoid huge pressure on dynamic memory allocation and get other benefits.

```
void connect_sensors()
{
    std::for_each(sensors.begin(),sensors.end(),[](Sensor & sensor) { sensor.connect(); });
}
```

I use *devices* to access the objects when I need to treat them similarly.

```
void render() {
   std::for_each(devices.begin(),devices.end(),[](Device *device) { device->render(); });
}
```

The drawback is that I have to update both specific arrays and devices when I add/remove an object. So, I have a risk forgetting to update one of them.

Another approach would be throw out the devices vector and call render method for each specific vector, but this would be a huge code duplication and risks of forgetting to add for_each for a new type in the other places.

So, the problem I am trying so solve is to avoid code/data duplication and risks of getting them out of sync.

Why I don’t want to use only devices container and allocate all objects implicitly with new operator:

1. There are many objects in containers and I don’t want to iterate through all of them when I need objects of the specific type. I can solve this with partitioning, but this will overcomplicate the solution.
2. They have quite different interfaces and I don’t want to dynamic_cast every time I need a specific type.

I just need something that will represent “all containers” entity for the client code where all objects need to be considered similarly. What is the best way to achieve this?

Actually, I don’t want to pay for extra indirection and vtable, so if there is a solution (templates, metaprogramming) which would allow to get rid of devices vector, this would be just perfect.

Comment: Do you know what `std::variant` is, how it works and how to use it?

Comment: How many different types deriving from `Device` do you have?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, thank you. It seems to be very close to what I am looking for, with only one reservation. I see that it adds an extra member (index) of 4 bytes to every structure and I use them to pass arrays to CUDA so tight memory packing helps sometime. Anyway, Iet me investigate this option deeper before I update my question.

Comment: @PaulSanders, about a dozen and what's worse, I add/remove them often during development due to research nature of the project.

Comment: I have an application that operates test fixtures.  I have a similar hierarchy, including power supplies and o'scopes.  I have a `Test_Fixture` base class and several instances.  Each test fixture instance has a container of pointers to `Device`.  The containers can be hard coded, or they can be assembled from an initialization file.

Comment: C++ is, fundamentally, a type-safe language. Somewhere, somehow, you're going to pay the piper. Either via a virtual function dispatch or by storing an extra byte, or two, in order to ensure type-safety. In order to accomplish something like this, somehow, and implement a type-safe solution without a single extra byte being used somewhere will require breaking multiple fundamental rules of physics of our shared universe. That is, in my opinion, very unlikely. So, you'll have to pick where you wish to pay the piper, for type safety: virtual function, or type identification.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, some questions. (1) I am a little bit confused with your terms, do you mean "pointers to Text_Fixture" or "pointers to Device"?  (2) With "several instances", do you mean several classes derived from Text_Fixture or real objects? If objects, do you mean objects  of Text_Fixture class or derived classes? I assume "several instances of the classes derived from Test_Fixture", is this correct vision?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I agree and my questions where the price will be less in terms of safety, efficiency and implementation easiness. We came to some option here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75972926/virtually-sequentially-concatenate-two-c-stdvectors, but it revealed many side effects, like safety on assignment operator and so on. So, the question is, how to write this code to make sure that the developer won't miss to sync vectors or make some other mistake?

Comment: I have a pointers to an instance of Text_Fixture descendants; Every Test_Fixture (descendant) has a container of pointers to devices.  The base classes are abstract class so that instances cannot be created of them.  For example, I have a `class Stapler_TF : public Test_Fixture;`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, so, are you saying that each descendant class has a container of pointers to devices? Am I correct that this is a static member, one for all objects of this descendant class? Or are you saying that each object of every descendant class has a container of pointers to devices? Am I correct that this list contains only device pointers to real objects or this type (so, Stapler_TF contains a container of pointers to Test_Fixture which really points to Stapler_TF objects or they points to all Test_Fixture descendant class objects?)

Comment: A Test_Fixture has a container of zero or more devices.  So, the `Stapler_TF` class can have a `std::vector<Device *>` as a data member.  I did not say static.  The `Stapler_TF` constructor can test device connections, such as an O'scope.  If the O'scope is connected and functioning, then an instance is created and the pointer to the O'scope Device instances is appended to the vector.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, now I get the idea. I was a little bit confused with the names and architecture. Now I see it. The problem that it is covered in my section "Why I don’t want to use only devices container and allocate all objects implicitly with new operator". You just use polymorphism and keep pointers to base class object in the container which I want to avoid because of the reasons under this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is of course a **template**:

```
template<class T>
void render(std::vector<T> &v) {
  std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),[](T &t) { t.render(); });
}
```

The issue remains of how to avoid writing several long lists of calls to such a function template (which might fall out of sync), but that can be addressed with… **another** template:

```
struct Sensor {
   void setup();
   void render();
   void connect();
};

struct Regulator {
   void setup();
   void render();
};

class Scheme {
   std::vector<Sensor> sensors;
   std::vector<Regulator> regulators;
   // many containers

   template<class F>
   void all(F &&f) {
      std::for_each(sensors.begin(),sensors.end(),f);
      std::for_each(regulators.begin(),regulators.end(),f);
      // ...
   }
};
```

Clients then look like

```
void setup(Scheme &s) {s.all([](auto &d) {d.setup();});}
void render(Scheme &s) {s.all([](auto &d) {d.render();});}
```

These could be made member functions, with `all` a private helper, if no clients need to, say, interleave calls to `setup` and `render` on successive devices.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly what I was asking for and this helped me understand that my question was wrong, because in most of the places in the code I iterate through these elements, doing some calculations on interactions of the elements. I will create new more specific question on this. (Regardless, I will use your approach, as well, of course).

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [ECS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) sets out to solve, separating data into individual components (in your case, I see a `Renderable` component and a `Connectable` component at least, possibly with an additional component to store the identification of your device), and allowing separate systems to work on just the components they care about (the `Render` system runs on all `Renderable` entities, the `Connect` system runs on all `Connectable` entities etc).

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of ECS and put it aside for a time because of extra complexity and high level of indirection. Really, I am not very happy with "Engine->GetComponentManager()->GetComponent<TransformComponent>(RB->GetOwner())" style code, but now I see that the model worth more close attention and practicing. In my case I have lots of derived-class-specific functions; would they fit into model? I see it works well for "unified" objects, but would it work for very distinct classes? Would it help solve the problem of iteration through *Device*s while implementing interactions between objs?

Comment: Your question feels very much like an XY problem, you’re not iterating over devices for the fun of it but to apply an algorithm over something device-like. And that’s exactly what the S in ECS is, the system that works on device-likes.

Comment: As to the API, that’s between you and your library. My personal implementation of ECS [is nothing like that](https://github.com/myblindy/tweey/blob/35eaf07d1e4f5876f6693a334de7bbb34ac2afcc/tweey/Systems/ThoughtIconExpirySystem.cs#L16), for example.